# How to serve cached images in django sorl-thumbnails ? It's raising 404s

Tags: django, memcached, sorl-thumbnail

I'm new to sorl-thumbnail and I am generating thumbnails that behave like they should work fine but they don't. Here's an example of what I'm doing

```
         {% thumbnail "http://www.tlswebsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/django-logo-negative.png" "200x200" as im %}
            <img src="{{ im.url }}">
            {% empty %}
              <p>No image</p>
          {% endthumbnail %}
```

I'm using memcached with the default configuration and the stats look like my thumbnails are actually stored in the cache. The thumbnail appears in the my folder /proj/myapp/cache/x/xx/xx.jpg

But the site raises a 404. Which I think is normal, as there is no URL pointing to that /cache directory.

I checked the doc, they don't seem to say that there is anything particular to do about this. Did I miss an obvious step somewhere ?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: did you configure a server for your media files?

Comment: check this out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development

Comment: I actually moved everything to S3 with django-storage and it's working like a charm, thanks for the hint though

Comment: because it serves your media files. when using the default storage, you need to configure it by yourself

Answer (score 0):

Using django-storage to ship everything to S3 cleared that issue